# read a csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm struggling with reading and writing a csv file using power shell. I need to read a file containing three columns  Servers, Users, Status

I've completed the first step (read in the file)

The next step is to split the data in the Status field by its delimiter ';'  (I have that as well)

Now where the problem comes in is where I loop thru a Get-ADUser and build the print line putting all the values in the foreach loop together - seperated with a ';'. (new status field)

Then of course at the conclusion write out the completed file.

so the input file is a csv that contains the following

Server      Users        Status
ABC         xtom
JKL
CDEA        msall;jbec

The output csv would be

Server Users        Status
ABC    xtom         xert.tom@abc.com;
JKL
CDEA   msall;jbec   mik.sall@abc.com;jay.bec@abc.com

my code as it stands

```
$List = Import-Csv -Path "c:\data\infile.csv"

$outarray = @()

foreach ($item in $List) 
{
   Write-output $item

   $Servers= $($item.Server)
   $Users  = $($item.Users)
   $Status = $($item.Status)

   if ($Users.length -gt 0)
   {
      $CharArray =$Users.Split(";")

      Foreach ($i in $CharArray)
      { 
      
        $email = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $i} | Select -Property UserPrincipalName
        $outarray = $email

      }
   }

}

$outarray |  Export-Csv "c:\data\testout.csv" -noType
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

The csv input file

```
Server,Users,Status
ABC,xtom,
JKL,,
CDEA,msall;jbec,
```

the csv output file

```
Server,Users,Status
ABC,xtom,xert.com@abc.com
JKL,,
CDEA,msall;jbec,mik.sall@abc.com;jay.bec@abc.com
```

Comment: Can you add a literal representation of how the CSV looks, open the CSV with notepad and copy paste the headears and one or two lines of column values (leave the commas and semicolons as they're).

Comment: Server,Users,Status
ABC,xtom,
JKL,,
CDEA,msall;jbec,

Comment: Not in a comment; [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67167856/edit) instead.

Comment: Can you code-format the input and output csv lines, and add an example of each line? It's hard to tell what you want as an output. Do you want just the `UserPrincipalName` or a csv of with columns like `Server | Users | Status` with the user column split up.

Comment: You might find it useful to look at the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.1) and [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.1) operators.

Comment: What im looking for is to take each line, lookup the UserPrincipalName for each item in cell b, insert the data returned from the adlookup with a semicolon between the values into column c, then move to the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly what you need this code should work for you:

```
$List = Import-Csv -Path "c:\data\infile.csv"

$outarray = [system.collections.generic.list[pscustomobject]]::new()

foreach ($item in $List) 
{
    Write-output $item

    $Server = $($item.Server)
    $Users  = $($item.Users)
    $Status = $($item.Status)

    if ($Users)
    {
        $CharArray = $Users.Split(";")

        $email = $(
        Foreach ($i in $CharArray)
        {   
            $usr=(Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $i}).UserPrincipalName
            if($usr){$usr}
        }) -join ';'
    }

    $outarray.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Server = $Server
            Users = $Users
            Status = $email
    })

}

$outarray |  Export-Csv "c:\data\testout.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

It's worth mentioning that `userPrincipalName` is definitely not the same thing as `mail` even though they can look the same this may not always be the case.

Also, if `$i` will actually contain `samAccountNames` then `-Filter {....}` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks so much. One last question, how do i eliminate the semicolon on the -join statement when the Get-ADUser fails to return a user?

Comment: @Danny54 see my edit, a simple `if` condition should do the trick